# Internal error for PHPmailer on server

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$msg  = 'God Bless You';
    $subj = 'Ryan D\'souza Photgraphy Invoice';
    $to   = $_POST['email'];
    $from = 'emailaddres';
    $name = $_POST['client'];

    smtpmailer($to,$from, $name ,$subj, $msg);

    function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name = 'Ryan D\'souza Photgraphy', $subject, $body)
    {
        global $error;
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
            $mail->Port = 465;  
            $mail->Username = 'username';  
            $mail->Password = 'password';   

        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From="emailaddres";
        $mail->FromName="Ryan D'souza Photgraphy";
        $mail->Sender=$from; // indicates ReturnPath header
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $from_name); // indicates ReplyTo headers
        $mail->AddCC('cc@site.com.com', 'CC: to site.com');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAttachment('pdfs/'.$_POST['client'].'.pdf');
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        $mail->AddAddress("emailaddres");
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'Message sent!';
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I'm using PHP mailer to attach a file and send mail. the code works on local system but when I upload it on the server that time it gives me Internal server error. I tried commenting and print each line of the code and found out that i get at $mail->Send().

Comment: Can you please add the exception message of the exception that occures at `Send()`? Edit your post.

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@main-hosting.eu to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: You think it might be the server Error? I mean some configurations have to be changed on server

Comment: Your web server's error log will tell you what actually broke. Why are you returning true when sending fails?

Comment: I have the same problem, how to fix it?